# Immediate observable not firing through Observable.defer

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to use RxJS caching to avoid unnecessary repetion of certain HTTP calls. While experimenting with `publishReplay`, I ended up with the following snippet (inspired by [this blog post](https://riptutorial.com/rxjs/example/26490/caching-http-responses)):

```
let counter = 1;
const updateRequest = Observable.defer(() => mockDataFetch())
  .publishReplay(1, 1000)
  .refCount();

function mockDataFetch() {
  return Observable.of(counter++)
    .delay(0); // <-- delay by 0 milliseconds
}

function mockHttpCache() {
  return updateRequest
    .take(1);
}

setTimeout(() => mockHttpCache().subscribe(val => console.log("Response 50:", val)), 50);
setTimeout(() => mockHttpCache().subscribe(val => console.log("Response 500:", val)), 500);
setTimeout(() => mockHttpCache().subscribe(val => console.log("Response 1500:", val)), 1500);
```

This works as expected and yields the output:

> ```
> 'Response 50:', 1
> 'Response 500:', 1
> 'Response 1500:', 2
> ```

However, when removing `.delay(0)` from the inner observable, making it immediate, the wrapper yields no more results after the caching duration has passed. The output is then:

> ```
> 'Response 50:', 1
> 'Response 500:', 1
> ```

It looks like `mockDataFetch` doesn't get called to gather new data even if there's no cached item anymore. Is this intended behaviour, and if so, what's the rationale behind it?

Comment: It's strange. It behaves like this only when combining `publishReplay()` and `refCount()` even though `delay()` should have no affect there. Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: Hi @martin, I don't think it's a bug, it's due to the fact that without `delay(0)`, everything happens synchronously, so the `RefCountSubscriber` does not behave as it _should_(i.e re-subscribing to the source), meaning that the `ReplaySubject` will receive the complete notification. And since `publishReplay` is using the same `ReplaySubject` instance, the new subscribers will subscribe to a completed subject.

Comment: What I find strange about this is that even when using `delay()` the `next` and `complete` notifications will emitted synchronously https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/delay.ts#L99. So that should be the same like without `delay()` because `take(1)` will unsubscribe immediately before `delay()` should be able to emit the `complete` notification. But maybe the problem happens here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/multicast.ts#L64-L65. I think you're correct about the ReplaySubject being stopped because it receives `complete`.

Comment: @martin I'd say that the `dispatch` function is the action's task, which is scheduled [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/delay.ts#L120), which comes from `scheduleNotification`. And because the default scheduler is `AsyncScheduler`, it would be the same as delaying with `setTimeout(() => {}, 0);`, which means that `delay()` won't send the values synchronously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your code translated into RxJs `6.5.5`, along with some other small modifications:

```js
let counter = 1;
const updateRequest = defer(() => mockDataFetch())
  .pipe(
    publishReplay(1, 1000),
    refCount()
  );

function mockDataFetch() {
  console.log('RESUBSCRIBING');

  return of(counter++)
    .pipe(
      // delay(0), // <-- delay by 0 milliseconds
    );
}

function mockHttpCache() {
  return updateRequest
    .pipe(
      take(1),
    );
}

setTimeout(
  () => mockHttpCache().subscribe(val => console.log("Response 50:", val), null, () => console.warn('complete[1]')
), 50);
setTimeout(
  () => mockHttpCache().subscribe(val => console.log("Response 500:", val), null, () => console.warn('complete[2]')
), 500);
setTimeout(
  () => mockHttpCache().subscribe(val => console.log("Response 1500:", val), null, () => console.warn('complete[3]')
), 1500);
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-conn-obs-subject-sync?file=index.ts).

---

### Without `delay(0)`

Let's first have a look at how [`publishReplay` is implemented](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/publishReplay.ts#L21-L24):

```js
const selector = typeof selectorOrScheduler === 'function' ? selectorOrScheduler : undefined;
const subject = new ReplaySubject<T>(bufferSize, windowTime, scheduler);

return (source: Observable<T>) => multicast(() => subject, selector!)(source) as ConnectableObservable<R>;
```

As we can see, it returns a `ConnectableObservable`, due to [`multicast`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/multicast.ts#L49-L53):

```js
const connectable: any = Object.create(source, connectableObservableDescriptor);
connectable.source = source;
connectable.subjectFactory = subjectFactory;

return <ConnectableObservable<R>> connectable;
```

And this is how [`refCount`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/refCount.ts#L70-L83) looks like:

```js
// `connectable` - the `ConnectableObservable` from above
constructor(private connectable: ConnectableObservable<T>) { }

// `call` - called when the source is subscribed
// `source` - the `ConnectableObservable` from above
call(subscriber: Subscriber<T>, source: any): TeardownLogic {
  const { connectable } = this;
  (<any> connectable)._refCount++;

  const refCounter = new RefCountSubscriber(subscriber, connectable);
  const subscription = source.subscribe(refCounter);

  if (!refCounter.closed) {
    (<any> refCounter).connection = connectable.connect();
  }

  return subscription;
}
```

Now, let's have a closer look at [`ConnectableObservable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/ConnectableObservable.ts#L12), especially at the `subscribe` method:

```js
// Invoked as a result of `const subscription = source.subscribe(refCounter);` from `refCount`
_subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber<T>) {
  return this.getSubject().subscribe(subscriber);
}

protected getSubject(): Subject<T> {
  const subject = this._subject;
  if (!subject || subject.isStopped) {
    this._subject = this.subjectFactory();
  }
  return this._subject!;
}
```

Where `subjectFactory` returns a `ReplaySubject` instance. What basically happens on `const subscription = source.subscribe(refCounter);` is that a `RefCounterSubscriber` will be added to the `ReplaySubject`'s list of active subscribers. A `RefCounterSubscriber` keeps track of the number of subscribers and when the are no more subscribers, it will automatically subscribe to the source when a new subscriber is registered(while using the same `ReplaySubject`) instance.

Next, `(<any> refCounter).connection = connectable.connect();` will be invoked.

[`connectable.connect()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/ConnectableObservable.ts#L38-L51) does the following:

```js
  connect(): Subscription {
  let connection = this._connection;
  if (!connection) {
    this._isComplete = false;
    connection = this._connection = new Subscription();
    connection.add(this.source
      .subscribe(new ConnectableSubscriber(this.getSubject(), this)));
    if (connection.closed) {
      this._connection = null;
      connection = Subscription.EMPTY;
    }
  }
  return connection;
}
```

When these lines are reached:

```js
connection.add(this.source
    .subscribe(new ConnectableSubscriber(this.getSubject(), this)));
```

the source(e.g `mockDataFetch()`) will actually be subscribed.

Now, `of(counter)` is implemented like this(roughly):

```js
// In this case, `arr = [counter]`
new Observable(subscriber => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    subscriber.next(arr[i]);
  }

  subscriber.complete();
});
```

This means that `take(1)` will be reached first and when it happens, it will emit that value and then it will send a `complete` notification(by invoking [`Subscriber._complete()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L147-L150) eventually):

```js
protected _complete(): void {
  this.destination.complete();
  this.unsubscribe();
}
```

So, besides sending the `complete` notification further in the chain, it will also unsubscribe. It will eventually reach the `RefCounterSubscriber`'s unsubscription logic, but it won't work *as expected*, because everything is happening **synchronously**. In *normal* circumstances, if the `ReplaySubject` was left without any subscribers, the source would be unsubscribed.

But since it's being left without subscribers **while subscribing to the source**, there will be a slightly different behavior. The `ReplaySubject`'s subscribers list will be empty, but the source **won't be unsubscribed**, because, as mentioned above, it is still in the *subscription process*.

What it means in the end is that `subscriber.complete();` will be called, which in turn will cause the `ReplaySubject` to receive a `complete` notification. But remember that the same `ReplaySubject` will be used when the source *would be re-subscribed*.

Next time when it would subscribe to the source again, [these lines](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/refCount.ts#L75-L82) would be reached:

```js
const refCounter = new RefCountSubscriber(subscriber, connectable);
// Subscribing to a **completed** Subject
// If the Subject is completed, an EMPTY subscription will be reached
const subscription = source.subscribe(refCounter);

if (!refCounter.closed) { // Since `closed === true`, this block won't be reached
  (<any> refCounter).connection = connectable.connect();
}

// Returning the EMPTY subscription
return subscription;
```

[`EMPTY` implementation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subscription.ts#L21-L24).

This would be the flow of the program, without `delay(0)`

```js
setTimeout(
  // Source emits and the value is cached by the subject for 1 second
  // `take(1)` is reached
  // Send the value, then a `complete` notif.
  // But since sending a `complete` notif involves unsubscribing as well
  // The current subscriber will be removed from the `ReplaySubject`'s subscribers list
  // Then, the `ReplaySubject` will receive the `complete` notification and the subject becomes **completed**
  () => mockHttpCache().subscribe(val => console.log("Response 50:", val), null, () => console.warn('complete[1]')
), 50);
setTimeout(
  // Subscribing to a **completed** subject, but because it's a `ReplaySubject`
  // We'd still be getting the cached values, along with a `complete` notification
  () => mockHttpCache().subscribe(val => console.log("Response 500:", val), null, () => console.warn('complete[2]')
), 500);
setTimeout(
  // Since `1`'s time expired at 1 second, the `ReplaySubject` will only send a complete notification
  () => mockHttpCache().subscribe(val => console.log("Response 1500:", val), null, () => console.warn('complete[3]')
), 1500);
```

This is what will get logged:

```
RESUBSCRIBING
Response 50:
1
complete[1]
Response 500:
1
complete[2]
complete[3]
```

---

### With `delay(0)`

This relies on some details mentioned in the previous section.

`delay(0)` will schedule an action in the `AsyncScheduler`(by default) on every `nexted` notification. The action's task is to emit that received value after `0 ms` have passed. It's essentially the same as using `setTimeout`, which means it **will not be something synchronous**.

However, when using `of()`, the `complete` notification will be sent synchronously. [This is how `delay` deals with it](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/delay.ts#L153-L158):

```js
protected _complete() {
  // `this.queue` is populated when a `nexted` value arrives
  if (this.queue.length === 0) {
    this.destination.complete();
  }

  // Unsubscribe from the previous items from the chain
  // What's further will **not** be affected
  this.unsubscribe();
}
```

The `complete` notification will eventually be sent when the queue is empty. But keep in mind that this is all **asynchronous**, meaning that the `RefCountSubscriber` will behave *normally*.

This would be the flow of the program, with `delay(0)`:

```js
setTimeout(
  // Subscribing to the source, which emits a value and a complete notif, synchronously
  // `delay` schedules an action that will do its job in 0ms(still asynchronously)
  // The value is emitted by the `delay`'s scheduled action
  // `take(1)` is reached
  // The value will be passed along then a `complete` notif will be sent
  // Then, the source will be unsubscribed
  // Due to `refCount`, the complete notif that came from the source
  // Won't reach the `ReplaySubject`. as it will already be unsubscribed from the source
  () => mockHttpCache().subscribe(val => console.log("Response 50:", val), null, () => console.warn('complete[1]')
), 50);
setTimeout(
  // Since only `500ms` have passed, this subscriber will receive the cached value (`1`)
  // and a `complete` notification, due to `take(1)`
  // But since `take(1)` operates synchronously, the `RefCountSubscriber` would be closed already, so the source won't be re-subscribed (//1)
  () => mockHttpCache().subscribe(val => console.log("Response 500:", val), null, () => console.warn('complete[2]')
), 500);
setTimeout(
  // `1500ms` passed, since `1000ms` the cache is empty
  // So the `take(1)` operator will receive nothing, meaning that the source
  // will be re-subscribed
  () => mockHttpCache().subscribe(val => console.log("Response 1500:", val), null, () => console.warn('complete[3]')
), 1500);
```

Output:

```
RESUBSCRIBING
Response 50:
1
complete[1]
Response 500:
1
complete[2]
RESUBSCRIBING
Response 1500:
2
complete[3]
```

`//1` in order to see that the `RefCountSubscriber` is **closed**, you can open the dev tools in your SB project, press `CTRL + P`, type `refCount.ts` and place a **logpoint** on line 78(e.g: `'refCounter.closed', refCounter.closed`):

```js
if (!refCounter.closed) { /* ... */ }
```

and if you comment out the last `setTimeout(() => {}, 1500)`,
you should see something like this:

```
refCounter.closed
false
RESUBSCRIBING
Response 50:
1
complete[1]
Response 500:
1
complete[2]
refCounter.closed // Closed due to `take(1)`
true
```

Comment: I'm sorry I only have one upvote to give this answer - *very* well done!

Comment: @SeanVieira thank you! It was a very interesting problem :)

Comment: Wow, pretty subtle what's going on here. So I suppose using this with HTTP request observables as source should be fine, as those will always be async anyway.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach, yes. If the source is async, then there should be no problems.